# Ceiling Fan Loose Wires

Tags: electrical

Our ceiling fan's pull cord broke off into the mechanism that controls off to speed 3. When trying to get to the remaining beaded cord, the actual mechanism broke. Now we have loose exposed wires. What are my options to just protect the now loose wires from touch metal or other wires. Do I need wire caps? Is there any quick solution to leave it as is safely for now?  Thanks.

Brown, Purple, Grey, Black are exposed.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the check mark, but I don't think I've fully solved your problem. You've still got mismatched wires & I don't know enough to tell you which one to connect to which. I'm sure someone will be along shortly to help out. I must say, though, that the brown, purple and grey look like they've never been connected to anything - those look like factory-spec wire twists there! How many little wire nuts did you find loose in the housing when you took the lid off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting to prevent shorts until you get it properly fixed, you could wrap each individual bare wire end with electrical tape.

If you're looking to repair it, there should be wire nuts in the fan housing somewhere that fell off. Reinstall those, wiring matching wire colors together. If there are mismatched colors, post a pic & someone will guide you.

Answer (score 0):

Wire nuts. Big name is Ideal but any UL listed will do.

Comment: I think calling wire nuts without a brand is the same as calling NMB Romex those are the names most often used I know I use wire nuts even though I prefer scotch locks , naw wire nuts sounds better.